# How can I restore the original theme

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I was changing the theme's coloring, and made my own custom theme. When I load blender the colorig is normal and I can load my colorful theme from the menu in user preferences. However, I then also changed some of the layout- example: I changed it from cycles to game engine, the timeline to the logic editor, and a bunch of other customizations. then I saved the user preferences, but I had my slightly more colorful theme selected when I saved it. Now when I open blender it looks like this! [image]

In the user preferences window under the theme tab, the default theme isn't there. How can I get it back without loading factory settings and losing all the other customizations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click *Reset to default theme* in *User Preferences > Themes*:

[image]

Then press *Save user settings* to save it.