# How to animate a character walking around?

Tags: animation, rigging

I've rigged a character and started animating it, but I've had problems trying to re-use poses after the character has walked around and is facing a different direction (or even the same direction, but after rotating 360°)

Should I parent the rig to an empty and do the rotating/whole character translations with the empty? How will I prevent the feet from sliding around then?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rigify and MHX use a bone called master. In order to apply poses independently of position and orientation the master bone which must not be added to the poses. 
Parenting the rig to an empty might also work.

[image]

[image]

When the feet start to slide around the walkcycle is too slow for use with the movement. In this case you can select the walkcycles keyframes and scale them until it looks right.

Comment: Good answer +1,however, I should DV it because you use purple in the UI

Comment: @X-27 What is the official Blender.SE theme?

Comment: um.... I use the default theme so I'd guess that that is the official theme

Comment: @Stacker, we're just too lazy to change it.. :P. your theme does seem a little... dark.

Comment: @VinceScalia I think this should be the default theme http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck5t3.png  (Came form this question)  http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14682/5426  DO NOT flag this as "The linked image is so horrendously ugly."

Comment: well my wacky brother thinks it looks better...